# Error: mediaplayer start called in state 0 error(-38,0)

Tags: java, android, media-player

i am new to android i have written the code on which links the mediaplayer to play songs

i have created a folder path="//localhost/Android/sd/vande.mp3 file is present

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button start,pause,stop;
boolean flag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    try{
    mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Android/music/vande.mp3");

    mp.prepare();

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
    { 
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) 
        {  
            //mp.start();
            flag = true; 
        } 

    });
    if(flag ==true)
    {
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.pause();
        }
    });
}}
```

but file is not playing when i checked the logcat there is an error popped up "start called in state 0 error  (-38,0)

can anyone help to resolve this code

thanks in advance

Comment: i tried onPreparedListener instead of onClickListener

Comment: calling start before media player is prepared

Comment: Environment line check whether i have used correct path @Raghunandan

Comment: start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.prepare();                                         mp.start();
        }
    }); correct i have to use prepare then start correct @Raghunandan

Comment: `mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
 mp.start();
  }
});`

Comment: but i have declared start for button1 where should i use that one when i click button it should start @Raghunandan

Comment: its upto you to decide and code

Comment: k yaar  but when i click start it is not playing so i am asking thats it @Raghunandan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51105/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-sandeep-v)

Comment: can u add the code which we discussed yesterday @Raghunandan such that it will be helpful to the people and me as well

Comment: posted the code. Check if it works and you can accept the same

Comment: ya sure i will @Raghunandan

Comment: wait i will edit the code tell whether it is correct or not @Raghunandan

Comment: hey i didnt add the permission in manifest internet permission @Raghunandan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait till the media player is prepared before calling start

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(
new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) 
 { 
    mp.start();  
 }
 });
```

If you want to start the player on button click. You can have a flag. `boolean flag=false;`

Then

```
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) 
 { 
   flag= true; 
 }
```

Then in onClick

```
if(flag ==true)
{
  mp.start();
}else
{
     // media player not prepared
}
```

Comment: i have edited this code @Raghunandan but it is still taking long why i dont know

Comment: @SandeepV coz media player is still not prepared. You need to wait for that to happen

Comment: Oh k how much time it takes usually there is any option such that we can start the player immediately @Raghunandan

Comment: @SandeepV check the flag inside on click. can't tell the time

Comment: i havent added the permission internet one now i will check it @Raghunandan

Comment: I have edited the above code check once i have done it correctly @Raghunandan

Comment: @SandeepV you are not streaming audio from internet so it makes no sense to have internet permission

Comment: Emulator without GPU Emulation detected @Raghunandan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51168/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-sandeep-v)